# Wysihtml5 in rails_admin disappeared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I have added `gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'` to my Gemfile. So I'm using this gem with rails_admin.

I have a model called "News" in my project. It looks like this:

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo
    attr_accessible :photo, :header,:caption,:body,:photo_file_name,:photo_content_type,:photo_file_size
    rails_admin do
      field :photo,:paperclip
      field :header
      field :caption
      field :body, :wysihtml5
  end
end
```

I have files `bootstrap-wysihtml5.css` and `bootstrap-wysihtml5.js` in `app/assets/stylesheets` and `app/assets/javascripts` directories.

This worked fine some time ago. I had wysihtml5-textfield.

But yesterday wysihtml5 panel just disappeared and now my field body looks like ordinary textfield. I haven't touched "News" model and logs doesn't give any errors.

What is going on here?